# how to import my module in same folder i try to import that it show invalid decimal literal

Tags: python-3.x

Project path

```
My_project
    ├── src
         ├── __init__.py
         ├── 01_Data_collection.py
         ├── 02_Data_pre_processing.py
         ├── 03_Feature_selection.py
         ├── 04_WoE_Calcuration.py
         └── 05_Model_Tarin.py
```

can't not import my module, used with file 05_Model_Tarin.py
console it show  SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal

```
from src.04_woe_calcuration import WoE_Binning


    from src.04_woe_calcuration import WoE_Binning
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal
```

I try to used  sys.path.insert already
change working directory already

Please advise
THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python identifiers can not start with a number.
Similarly, you cannot import module names that start with a number.

Either rename your modules, if not the do this:

```
import importlib
foo = importlib.import_module('src.04_woe_calcuration')
bar = foo.bar
```